# Git didn't remove submodule after reverting main repository before it was added

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-revert

Here's how this happened:

1. I checked-out a branch which has a new submodule added to it.
2. Then I went back to a commit on a different branch when the submodule wans't added.
3. Now I can't compile because the checked-out submodule is still on disk; the files exist and if I go to root directory on terminal it's still there.

So how do I fix this? Why didn't git delete the folder when I went back to a commit where it never existed.

I've tried:

- `git submodule update` on main repo.
- `git reset --hard` in the repo of submodule.
- `git reset --hard` in the main repo.

Nothing can delete this. I don't want to delete it manually because that is not the git way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how do I fix this?

Manually remove all the submodule files from your work-tree: `rm -rf submodule` for instance.

> Why didn't git delete the folder when I went back to a commit where it never existed.

Submodules are messy.

Remember, a submodule, in Git, is really just another Git repository.  This other Git repository is totally and completely independent of your main (superproject) repository.  Or rather, it would be—you'd just have two separate clones, side by side, with no interaction at all between them—except for the fact that you've stuck the submodule clone into the work-tree for the *superproject*.  And, in the process:

- In modern Git, the repository itself gets "absorbed" into the superproject's repository directory (so that there's no `.git` sub-*folder* but instead a `.git` *file* in the work-tree copy of the checked-out commit from the submodule).
- The superproject's Git records stuff *about* the submodule in the superproject's configuration (not just the `.gitmodule` file) and in some commits.  In particular, in commits where the submodule is supposed to be checked out at some particular hash ID, the hash ID itself is stored as a *gitlink* entry in each commit.
- The superproject's Git keeps `cd`-ing into the submodule and doing `git checkout <hash-id>` which detaches HEAD in the submodule.  (Exactly *when* it does this is another issue; it depends on whether you have submodule recursion enabled.)

In general, the fact that the submodule is a (mostly) independent repository inhibits the superproject Git from completely deleting it.  In this particular case, it probably *should* just go ahead and delete it as part of "update the submodule to the correct commit", because the "correct" commit in the submodule in question is "no commit at all - remove the submodule from the work-tree".  In the old days, before Git absorbed the `.git` directory into the superproject, this would literally destroy the submodule repository, which would be bad.<sup>1</sup>  In modern Git, it won't (once the submodule `.git` directory is absorbed at least), so it can be made to work.

---

<sup>1</sup>In many situations, it would be harmless but for the need to re-clone.  But suppose you made a superproject commit by (1) making a submodule commit on a new branch you made *in* the submodule; (2) exiting the submodule back to the superproject and updating the index gitlink entry to record the new hash ID in the submodule; (3) making the new commit.  You now have a submodule commit that is not pushed anywhere, but can and should be pushed before the superproject commit is pushed.

Now that you have this all set up, you decide to take a look at a historic commit.  You `git checkout <hash>` in the superproject, and that historic commit *doesn't* have the submodule checked out.  You have `submodule.recurse` set to `true` or have used `git checkout --recurse-submodules` so that the superproject brings the submodule to the correct (lack of) commit, and *removes the submodule*.

Since the `.git` directory literally lives *in* the submodule—inside the submodule's work-tree—this completely, irrevocably destroys the commit you made in the submodule, on the branch you made there, that you have not yet pushed.  So this *must not* be done.

Now that the `.git` directory itself lives elsewhere, removing the submodule bodily from the superproject's work-tree does not harm the submodule *repository*.  So now, this kind of removal would be safe.  Restoring the superproject to the latest commit can simply restore the submodule's work-tree, checking out the commit that is GC-protected by the submodule's repository's branch (still not yet pushed).